# Call Python cloud function from Angular

Tags: python, angular, typescript, axios, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed a cloud function written in Python to GCP.

```
from flask import escape
import functions_framework

@functions_framework.http
def hello_http(request):
    """HTTP Cloud Function.
    Args:
        request (flask.Request): The request object.
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#incoming-request-data>
    Returns:
        The response text, or any set of values that can be turned into a
        Response object using `make_response`
        <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.make_response>.
    """
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    else:
        name = 'World'
    return 'Hello {}!'.format(escape(name))
```

I am able to call this function from angular using `axios` for example. However, no data is sent through. If I print `request.data` in the python function it prints empty. Also `request_json` is always `None`.

```
axios.post('https://projektid.cloudfunctions.net/hello_http', { 
        data: 123
      })
      .then((result: any) => {
        console.log(result)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log('ERROR', err)
      });
```

Edit:
It works fine and passes the arguments if I call it from Python like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.post('https://projektid.cloudfunctions.net/hello_http', json={'data': 123})
print(r.text)
```

How can I correctly pass data to this python function from angular/typescript?

Comment: Are you allowing unauthenticated calls? https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#gcloud_4

Comment: Yes, allow unauthenticated is set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're calling your function from localhost make sure you're handling cors requests. You can find more information about that in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests).